# Mono: Issue with synchronous continuation tasks

Tags: c#, mono, task-parallel-library

I'm occasionally getting the following `InvalidOperationException` while running tasks on a custom `TaskScheduler` that I'm implementing.

Upon investigating the issue, it seems to be a bug in the Mono implementation. When a continuation task is marked with `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`, it will be passed to the task scheduler's `TryExecuteTaskInline` method; however, if the latter declines to execute it and returns `false`, then one will inevitably run into the following exception (per the code excerpts below).

Can someone suggest a way of resolving this on Mono? I was thinking of altering my [`TryExecuteTaskInline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449178.aspx) implementation such that it will always accept to execute synchronous continuations; however, I haven't been able to find a way of determining whether a task *is* a continuation (without using reflection).

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a continuation task
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Start (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronouslyCore (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ProcessCompleteDelegates () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Schedulers.WorkStealingTaskScheduler.DispatchLoop (CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm pasting below the relevant (stripped-down) sections...

…from [`TaskContinuation.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs):

```
class TaskContinuation
{
    public void Execute ()
    {
        // ...

        if ((continuationOptions & TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) != 0)
            task.RunSynchronouslyCore (task.scheduler);
        else
            task.Schedule ();
    }
}
```

…from [`Task.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs):

```
public class Task
{
    internal void RunSynchronouslyCore(TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        // ...

        if (scheduler.RunInline(this, false))
            return;

        Start(scheduler);
        Wait();
    }

    public void Start(TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        // ...

        if (IsContinuation)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Start may not be called on a continuation task");

        SetupScheduler(scheduler);
        Schedule();
    }
}
```

…and from [`TaskScheduler.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs):

```
public abstract class TaskScheduler
{
    protected abstract bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued);

    internal bool RunInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        // ...

        return TryExecuteTaskInline(task, taskWasPreviouslyQueued);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks quite simple to fix. The only alteration needed is changing https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs#L228 to call method Schedule instead of Start

Comment: Indeed, that's the proper fix; I didn't consider modifying the Mono source.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this issue but is constrained to use an unfixed version of Mono (up to and including Mono 3.0.12), you can use the following hack. It's inefficient since it needs to read the stack trace, so try to avoid the check in the majority of cases.

```
public class MyTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        if (this.CanInlineTasks() ||    // should return true most of the time
            IsSynchronousContinuationTask(task))
            return base.TryExecuteTaskInline(task, taskWasPreviouslyQueued);

        return false; 
    }

    private static bool IsSynchronousContinuationTask(Task task)
    {
        // assuming Mono
        string stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
        return stackTrace.Contains("System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronouslyCore") 
            && stackTrace.Contains("System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.Execute");
    }
}
```